# C# Can't access properties from class

Tags: c#

I have a some of the instructions from my course:
[image]

And When I try to acess the frequency and duration properties it says: "doesn't exist in current context."

Here is a some of my code:

```
namespace SongPlayer
{

// This class is provided as part of the Activity Starter program.
class Note
{
    // Define common note frequencies
    public static int NOTE_C = 524;
    public static int NOTE_D = 594;
    public static int NOTE_E = 660;
    public static int NOTE_F = 698;
    public static int NOTE_G = 784;
    public static int NOTE_A = 880;
    public static int NOTE_B = 988;

    // Define common note durations (in milliseconds)
    public static int DURATION_WHOLE = 1600;
    public static int DURATION_HALF = 800;
    public static int DURATION_QUARTER = 400;    

    // Declare the properties for this note
     public int Frequency;
     public int Duration;

    // This constructor requires the Frequency and Duration for this note
    public Note(int frequency, int duration)
    {
        this.Frequency = frequency;
        this.Duration = duration;

    }

}

// This class code is ADDED FOR ACTIVITY by the student
class Song
{
    // student code to implement the Song class goes here




        public string Name; //HERE
        public LinkedList<Note> notes; //HERE222
        public Song(string name) //This is a constructor method
        {
            this.Name = name; // "this.Name is referring to THERE while " = name " is reffering to the paramenter.
            this.notes = new LinkedList<Note>(); //This is refferring to THERE222
        }


        public void AddNote(int frequency, int duration)
          {
             Note MyNote = new Note(frequency, duration); //Class instance.
             notes.AddLast(MyNote);

          }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void Play()
    {
        foreach(Note MyNote23 in notes)
        {
          //I need to access the properties here
        }


    }


}

}
```

Here is another part of my code from another page:

```
private void initializeSongs()
    {
        songs = new LinkedList<Song>(); 
        //Song Mysong = new Song("Marry had a little lamb"); //I barly even know what i'm bloody doing. //inputting name
        Song song1 = new Song("Marry had a little lamb"); //retriver name.
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_B, Note.DURATION_QUARTER); //I think I have to do this for each note. Bloody damit.
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_A, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_G, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_A, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_B, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_B, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_B, Note.DURATION_HALF);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_A, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_A, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_A, Note.DURATION_HALF);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_B, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_D, Note.DURATION_QUARTER);
        song1.AddNote(Note.NOTE_D, Note.DURATION_HALF);


        songs.AddLast(song1); 
        SongListBox.Items.Add(song1.Name);   // add song name to list box


    }
```

I am new to c# and I have been trying for hours so please keep that in mind.

Comment: _"And When I try to acess the frequency and duration properties"_ I don't see any [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in your code.

Comment: Were you getting the error inside the `foreach`? Could you please show how were you trying to access the variables?

Comment: @SeM // Declare the properties for this note
     public int Frequency;
     public int Duration;

Comment: @Nathalia Soragge  This is what i'm trying to do: foreach(Note MyNote23 in notes)
            {
                Console.Beep(Frequency, Duration);
            }

Comment: @Samurai They are not [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), I would suggest you to use properties instead.

Comment: You have to tell from which object those variables are from. Like `Console.Beep(MyNote23.Frequency, MyNote23.Duration);`. And as SeM said, these are not properties. Properties should have a `{ get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your `Frequency` and `Duration` fields inside `foreach`:

```
foreach(Note MyNote23 in notes) 
{ 
    Console.Beep(MyNote23.Frequency, MyNote23.Duration); 
}
```

But I would suggest you to use [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of public fields.

References: **[Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have really been struggling learning C# from my online course because their teaching is just bad. When I search for lessons on youtube or other places I get a much better understanding of the subject material. Anyway I just wanted warn people about CompuScholar.

Comment: Your welcome, but I would suggest you to start reading `c#` books, instead of online courses or youtube videos and start to learn from very basics (declaring variables, types, methods, etc...) to somewhat have an idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling variable initialize in Note class inside Song class so you need to initialize Note class first then call its variable

```
public void Play()
{  
    Note note = new Note();

    foreach(Note MyNote23 in notes)
    {
        // I need to access the properties here
        int f = note.Frequency;
        int d = note.Duration;         
    }
}
```